# Java DateTimeFormat style: how to use 24 hours instead of AM/PM?

Tags: java, dateformatter

Java DateTimeFormat style: how to use 24 hours instead of AM/PM?

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.US);
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.print(date);
```

Output:

```
 11/13/21 6:41:43 PM
```

Need to be:

```
 11/13/21 18:41:43
```

Tried DateTimeFormatter, got same result:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    formatter.withLocale(Locale.US);
    String time = formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now());
```

This is for all different locales, so pattern will not work. Locale.US is an example only.

Comment: *Tried DateTimeFormatter* That’s good. I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: This has no effect in your code: `formatter.withLocale(Locale.US);`. `withLocale()` returns a *new* formatter with the specified locale. After that you are using the old one for formatting …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 24-hour time not appropriate for some locales

If localizing for the United States, then you should not be aiming for 24-hour time. 24-hour time is generally not used in the US outside of the military. Indeed, Americans often refer to it as "military time".

So your two statements "how to use 24 hours instead of AM/PM?" and "This is for all different locales" are contradictory. You cannot have it both ways. Either you want to control the output such as forcing 24 hour clock, *or* you want to localize.

If you really need a specific format, use the [Answer by lkatiforis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69960021/642706). But if your goal is to localize automatically, then you have to "go with the flow" regarding the results. Some locales will localize to 24-hour clock, and some locales will localize to 12-hour clock.

If you want to know where Java gets its rules for how to localize date-time values (translation, and cultural norms), see the [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) maintained by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium). The [CLDR is used by default](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) in most implementations of Java 9 and later.

If you want to see the various locales in action, here is some example code.

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 , 18 , 30 , 45 , 0 );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.SHORT );
for ( Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales() )
{
    String output = ldt.format( f.withLocale( locale ) );
    System.out.println( output + " | " + locale.getDisplayName( Locale.US ) + " | " + locale );
}
```

When run.

```
…
23.01.21 18:30 | Latvian | lv
23/01/2021, 18:30 | English (Niue) | en_NU
23/01/21 下午6:30 | Chinese (Simplified, Singapore) | zh_SG_#Hans
2021-01-23 6:30  | Fulah (Adlam, Liberia) | ff_LR_#Adlm
23/01/2021, 6:30 pm | English (Jamaica) | en_JM
23/01 2021 18:30 | Kako | kkj
2021-01-23 18:30 | Northern Sami (Latin, Norway) | se_NO_#Latn
2021-01-23 6:30 منجهند، شام | Sindhi (Arabic) | sd__#Arab
23/1/21 18:30 | Spanish (Bolivia) | es_BO
2021-01-23 ཆུ་ཚོད་ 6 སྐར་མ་ 30 ཕྱི་ཆ་ | Dzongkha (Bhutan) | dz_BT
23/1/21, 6:30 পি এম | Manipuri | mni
…
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first check if the date string matches any of the [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

If not, then you have to make your own `Formatter` using `.ofPattern(String pattern)` or .`ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Output:

> 11/13/21 19:41:43